# Упростите код программы

Tags: python

можно ли как-то **сделать код короче**? чтобы он был записан в минимально возможное кол-во строк?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
n = int(input())
 
mark = False
slash = False
 
char = 0
result = []
 
for i in range(n):
    string = input()
    while string[char] == " ":
        result.append(" ")
        char += 1
    for i2 in range(char, len(string)):
        if not slash:
            if string[i2] == "'":
                result.append(string[i2])
                mark = not mark
            elif string[i2] == "\\":
                result.append(string[i2])
                slash = True
            elif string[i2] == "#":
                if mark:
                    result.append(string[i2])
                else:
                    break
            elif string[i2] == " ":
                if mark:
                    result.append(string[i2])
                else:
                    if i2 + 1 != len(string):
                        if string[i2 + 1] == " ":
                            result.append("")
                        else:
                            result.append(string[i2])
            else:
                result.append(string[i2])
        else:
            slash = False
            result.append(string[i2])
    print("".join(result))
    result = []
    mark = False
    slash = False    
    char = 0
```

Comment: а код то правильно работает?

Comment: @Zhihar да, по крайней мере когда я тестил, все нормально вывело

Answer (score 5, accepted):

не меняя кода (не меняя логики и т.д.) код можно свернуть вот в такой:

```
strings = [input() for _ in range(int(input()))]

for string in strings:
    mark, slash, char, result = False, False, 0, []

    while string[char] == " ":
        result.append(" ")
        char += 1

    for i2 in range(char, len(string)):
        if not slash:
            mark = not mark if string[i2] == "'" else mark
            slash = string[i2] == "\\" or slash
            if string[i2] == "#" and not mark:
                break
            elif string[i2] == " " and not mark and i2 + 1 != len(string):
                result.append("" if string[i2 + 1] == " " else string[i2])
                continue
        else:
            slash = False

        result.append(string[i2])

    print("".join(result))
```

Comment: место `True if string[i2] == "\\" else slash` можно написать `string[i2] == "\\" or slash`